# How do you use a logic block within an element?

Tags: pug

As a newbie to the pugjs/jade template world I'm having a few issues.

Here is the fragment that isn't working as I want, expect, etc.:

```
div
  if typeof val == 'object'
    / call some mixin
  else
    #{val}
```

`#{val}` ends up creating a new element from the content of `val`. I do not want this. I want the body of `div` to be the evaluation of `val`.

Version:

`"pug": "^2.0.0-beta3"`

Answer (score 1):

Credit to the PUG team for helping me through the new syntax.

```
= val
// or for the es string interpolation syntax
= `interpolate this: ${val}`
```

Furthermore, the question is now asked incorrectly. The logic block was not the issue, it was how PUG was creating html that I had issue with.

Answer (score 0):

You need a pipe char before the `#{val}` in order for it to be interpreted as text:

```
div
  if typeof val == 'object'
    // call some mixin
  else
    | #{val}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I ended up getting some help from the pug family. I forgot to update this question. You are correct however there are additional ways. Like `= val` or `= \`interpolate this: ${val}\`` (for the new pug, es, string interpolation syntax)